# Software to change the volume of Cortana without changing the media volume

Tags: audio, windows-10

In Windows 10, the voice assistant Cortana is sometimes too loud or too quiet.  This is because it (she?) is tied to the media volume.

Can anyone recommend Windows 10 software that creates a separate volume slider for Cortana?